# Change pivot range without using dynamic range option

Tags: excel, vba

We are having a worksheet where we are deleting raw data and pasting new data every day. In the same workbook we have pivot table. However, it is in another sheet.

My problem is to select data source in pivot.

I am having a data starts from cell A1. However, I want to select data in pivot from cell b1 till last column. It means, I am selecting entire data except column A while changing pivot source data. I am unable to do so using vba.

Can we have any solution for this problem?

I have used below code. However, I am not getting out put.

```
'Workbooks("KAE LCO YTD").Sheets("SUMMARY").PivotTables("PivotTable2").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
'  PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("KAE NEB & VB YTD APR - LCO").Range("a3").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR2C2))
```

I am getting an error

> "Script out of range". error number : 9.

Comment: *"Script out of range"* means that either the name of the `Workbook`, the `Sheet` or the `PivotTable` does not exist. We cannot tell you which one it is. Try to debug your code step by step and check which one it is. • Workbooks usually need the complete file name including extension like `Workbooks("KAE LCO YTD.XLSM")` for example. If you mean the workbook this code is running in you can use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets…` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear.. thanks indeed.. I love your answer.